# Code runs in a different order than expected

Tags: angularjs

**JS**

```
<script type="application/javascript">
          var app = angular.module("app", []);

          app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
              $scope.data = [];
              $http.get("{{ url_for('data') }}")
                      .then(function (result) {
                          $scope.data = result.data;
                          console.log(result.data); //first
                      });
              console.log($scope.data); //second
...
</script>
```

first `console.log` returns the correct data (Array with one item), the second one returns empty Array.

Notice that the order of execution is not as the code:

**Console**

```
Array [  ]
Array [ "data" ]
```

Why the second console.log executes before the first one, How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `$http.get` is asynchronous so you don't know up-front how long it will take. `console.log($scope.data)` will be executed immediately following the `$http.get` request because the request will still be processing and waiting to return.

If you want to execute logic after your requests complete, you can add additional logic inside of the your `then()` and then chain them if you require additional requests to be executed. For instance,

```
              $http
              .get("{{ url_for('data') }}")
              .then(function (result) {
                  $scope.data = result.data;
                  // do more things
                  return $http.get('foo/bar')
              }).then(function (fooBar) {
                 // $scope.foo = bar;
              });
```

All `$http` calls return a promise so you're able to leverage the [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service to facilitate any promise specific functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Because the `http.get` is asynchronous i.e. it goes off and does something on another thread, whilst the rest of the program continues. By the time it's finished, and done it's `console.log`, the '2nd' `console.log` has already run.

Comment: How can I make $http.get called before anything else?

Comment: you can, if you use ngRoute

Comment: Put any additional code inside the then function that you're running on completion.

Comment: @Kikapi  I'm no JS expert, (hopefully one here will be able to answer this), but is there the concept of a 'waitForCompletion' flag, whereby the main thread will pause until that function has completed?

Of course, you have to be really careful here - suppose the http request takes 30 seconds? Of never completes? What do you do then.

Answer (score 1):

Angular's $http methods run asynchronously. This means the **console.log($scope.data);** will be excecuted first and the **console.log(result.data)** inside **then** will be excecuted when the promise from $http resolves.

Answer (score 0):

$http is the service which will be performed asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

This is because Angular's JavaScript runs asynchronously.  This means that It will keep running even though it's waiting on another task.  You should look up angular's guild on Promises.